# What is the difference between passing by reference and passing by value of arrays for recursive calls which share a reference via a closure?

Tags: javascript, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, recursive-backtracking

I was working on a solution to the following prompt: Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order.

The following code passes the tests:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
const permute = function(nums) {
  const results = [];
  const backtrack = (first = 0) => {
    if (first === nums.length) {
      results.push([...nums]);
      return
    }
    for (let i = first; i < nums.length; i++) {
      nums = swap(nums, first, i);
      backtrack(first + 1);
      nums = swap(nums, first, i)
    }
  }
  backtrack()
  return results
};

const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
  const temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
  return arr;
}
```

Consider an example for calculating the permutations where `nums = [1, 2, 3]`.

The gap in my understanding is apparent when I try to pass in `nums` to `results.push()` instead of `results.push([...nums])`, which returns the appropriate length result array, but is filled with `[1, 2, 3]` array at each index. Why is it necessary to make a shallow copy of `nums` here instead of just pushing `nums` directly? My understanding is that at the point in the recursive call where the base case is satisfied, `nums` will be whatever the current permutation is. Following the storing of our permutation, we backtrack/unswap `nums` and continue. I suppose it *must* be the case that all permutations in the `result` array will always reflect the current value of the reference element, but if that is the case, why is the final result array then filled with `[1, 2, 3]` for each element?

I thought I previously had a strong understanding of passing by reference vs passing by value but now I am doubting that understanding. Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I am almost there but can't quite get it to click.

Thanks for taking the time to read/help.

Comment: Does your code work? We fix code: [ask] post code: [mcve]

Comment: If you don't make a copy, then all the elements of `results` will be the same array, and when you swap elements it will affect all of them the same.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with call-by-reference vs call-by-value. There is only **one** array `nums` and another array `results` in your code (if not making the copy).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572)